# how to decode variable names in the HTML code of python

Tags: python

i am getting the following compilation error in the below code ,place where the error is happening is the code where the variable names are being decoded?how to decode the variable names in HTML code?

```
 File "test.py", line 33
    """)(% hostname,change,pwd,changeref,changeref)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Following is the Code:-

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import socket
import os

def email (body,subject):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
    msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    msg["From"] = "test@company.com"
    msg["To"] = "test@company.com"
    msg["Subject"] = '%s' % subject
    p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(msg.as_string())
def main ():
    change="2009"
    pwd=os.getcwd()
    changeref="refs/changes/59/206059/2"
    subject=change + "Test subject"
    hostname=socket.gethostname()
    body = ("""\
        <html>
         <head></head>
         <body>
          <p>%s<br>
            change - https://company/#/c/%s \n.<br>
            change Directory - %s for details \n.<br>
            Instructions: cd to the change Directory on hostname and execute the following commands \n.<br>
            git checkout %s<br>
            git fetch ssh://username@company:29418/platform/vendor/company-proprietary/code %s && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD".
         </p>
         </body>
        </html>
""")(% hostname,change,pwd,changeref,changeref)
    email(body,subject)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: and if you can, please use new style string formatting to lose the ugliness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is

```
"""
your HTML stuff here
""" % (hostname, change, pwd, changeref, changeref)
```

Note that the % sign goes outside the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Put the percentage sign out of the parenthesis:

```
         </body>
        </html>
""") % (hostname,change,pwd,changeref,changeref)
```